# Passing object's method pointer to function that accept [static method pointer / global function ] pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, casting

I have method

```
typedef void
(* JSErrorReporter)(JSContext *cx, const char *message, JSErrorReport *report);

JS_SetErrorReporter(JSContext *cx, JSErrorReporter er);
```

I would like to pass object's method rather than static method

```
JS_SetErrorReporter(cx,this->Reporter);//Failed !
```

where Reporter is object's method (not static)

```
JS_SetErrorReporter(cx,Reporter); //Passed
```

where Reporter is static method , declare as

```
static void SomeClass::reportError(JSContext *cx, const char *message, JSErrorReport *report)
```

Comment: Use `&SomeClass::reportError` then, `this->Reporter` is simply wrong syntax (even for member function pointers). A static method has no idea of `this` anyway.

Comment: What you can do is providing a static method, that gets the `this` pointer from the context somehow. I don't know if `JSContext` provides some `void* userData;` member, that could be used for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a member function pointer, you will have to get the syntax right, (not trivial)
For a boring function, taking and returning an int, that would be:

declaring a variable (also good for parameters):

```
int (SomeClass::*my_memfunc_ptr)(int);
```

assigning a variable:

```
 my_memfunc_ptr = &SomeClass::some_member_func;
```

calling:

```
  SomeClass *x = new SomeClass;
  int n = (x->*my_memfunc_ptr)(6);
```

I leave adapting this to your non-int uses to you.

Answer (score 0):

well avoid static function is easy use **__closure** function pointers instead:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class C2
    {
    public:
    void callback1() {}                     // your member function to pass to ...
    };

class C1                                    // some class with member function pointer usage
    {
    public:
    void (__closure *callback1)();          // member function pointer
    C1() { callback1=NULL; }                // constructor
    void do_something()                     // some function with use of callback1
        {
        if (callback1) callback1();
        }
    };

void some_function(void (__closure *f)())   // some function with member function parameter usage
    {
    if (f) f();
    }

void main()
    {
    C1 c1;
    C2 c2;
    c1.callback1=c2.callback1;
    c1.do_something();
    some_function(c1.callback1);
    some_function(c2.callback1);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**[edit 1]**

- but as RichardPlunkett outlined __closure it is just for borland/embarcadero compilers
- for VC/GCC/Intel ... compilers you need a workaround
- there are some out there.
- it looks like people prefer something called boost library
- here i found an example of __closure mimic http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/3078740.flat
- its in Russian but the source code is pretty clear even for us azbuka non-readers...

Comment: Thats a compiler specific extension isnt it?

Comment: uf you are right  I taked it for granted because i mostly code in borland so i didn't think of that :( http://objectmix.com/c/398370-how-translate-__closure-into-pure-c.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly. Because to call some non-static function you have to have `this` pointer but you don't pass it to `JS_SetErrorReporter` function.

Two possible solutions:

1. Change `JSErrorReporter` signature to accept +1 parameter of type `void *` and pass `this` pointer there.
2. Create a wrapper function as a global function, that also know required `this` pointer.